# Check whether my solution holds good or not.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

A sequence $\{x_n\}$ be such that every subsequence of it has a further subsequence converging to $1$ then show that the main sequence will converge to $1$.

**My work** :

Let us try to prove it by the method of contradiction.So,if possible let us assume that $\{x_n\}$ is not converging to $1$ then there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all natural number $k$ there exists a natural number $n \geq k$ for which $|x_n - 1| \geq \epsilon$. Let these natural numbers $n$ for $k = 1,2,...,r,...$ be respectively enumerated as $n_1,n_2,...,n_r,...$.Thus we can find out a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ of the main sequence $\{x_n\}$ which has no subsequence converging to $1$ according to the construction.Which contradicts our hypothesis.Hence our assumption is false.So,the main sequence should converge to $1$.

Is my process correct at all? Please check it.Thank you in advance.

Comment: The proof is basically good. One should be more explicit about how $n_1,n_2,\dots$ are obtained.

Comment: Andre do you aware me of the fact that how the theorem is proved directly?

Comment: Your way seems the natural one. I have not thought of anything substantially different.